# Hi i am getting the below error in prestashop 1.6 while accessing my website and prestashop admin. Please suggest with the fix

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Warning: require_once(/home/cconcept/public_html/classes/Tools.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cconcept/public_html/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php on line 111  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/cconcept/public_html/classes/Tools.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/cconcept/public_html/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php on line 111

Comment: Either `/home/cconcept/public_html/classes/Tools.php` does not exist, or is not readable by your webserver. Check the path and permissions.

Comment: the file exists and permission is also changed to 777 . Still same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the folders have `644` permission and all the files having `755` permission. Check all the permissions and set it accordingly and then check again.